# Hierarchical annotation on latex equation

Tags: equations

I have this code:

```
p = \Big[ \big[(v^\alpha _1, v^\beta _1), (v^\gamma _1, v^\delta _1, w_1)\big],
\big[(v^\alpha_2, v^\beta_2), (v^\gamma _2, v^\delta _2, w_2)\big],
... ,
\big[(v^{\omega-1} _n, v ^{\omega-1} _n), (v^\omega _n, v^\omega _n, w_n)\big]\Big]
```

Which produces:

[image]

Now, I'm not even sure if this is possible, but I figured I'd ask.

I'm trying to annotate this equation so it looks like this (or something in the same spirit):

[image]

How, if possible, can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

With `mathtools`, it is possible: it has  `\underbracket` and `\overbracket`commands:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{mathtools} %
\providecommand\given{}
 \DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\EV[1]{E}(){}{
 \renewcommand\given{\nonscript\,\delimsize\vert\nonscript\,}
 #1}
 \DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\Var[1]{V}(){}{
 \renewcommand\given{\nonscript\,\delimsize\vert\nonscript\,}
 #1}

\begin{document}

\[ p = \Big[ \big[\underbracket[0.6pt]{(\underbracket[0.6pt]{v^\alpha _1, v^\beta _1}_{\vphantom{b}a}), (\underbracket[0.6pt]{v^\gamma _1, v^\delta _1}_b, \underbracket[0.6pt]{w_1^{\vphantom{\gamma}}}_{\vphantom{b}c})}_d\big],
\big[(v^\alpha_2, v^\beta_2), (v^\gamma _2, v^\delta _2, w_2)\big],
\dots ,
\big[(v^{\omega-1} _n, v ^{\omega-1} _n), (v^\omega _n, v^\omega _n, w_n)\big]\Big] \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh this is great!!! An extra question: the underbracket "c" seems a little higher than a and b, any way to fix this?

Comment: @Rodolphe You can add a `\strut` before `w_1`.

Comment: That's right: ~1.6pt higher. And $a$ is 0.5pt higher than $b$. Two reasons: first $b$ has an ascender, while $a$ and $c$ don't. Second: the subscript of $w_1$ is higher than the subscripts of $u_1$ and $v_1$, because there is no exponent. I'll post a fine-tuned version in a moment, but the code will be less simple.

Comment: Please take a look at the updated version.

Comment: This is so cool @Bernard, my code doesn't need to be simple :)

Comment: OK. While you're at it, the rule thickness is adjustable and the height of the small tips at the ends too (see the doc, § 3.3.2, pp. 113–115).