# Multiple overbrackets

Tags: overbrace

Is there an easy way to use multiple overbrackets like in the attached image?
[image]

Comment: What you try so far?

Comment: Unluckily nothing, maybe I could draw lines using tikz but this would go far beyond my LaTex knowledge...

Comment: At least provide small document with your equation. You see, if the use of `tikz-cd` package can you help. On side is a lot of examples ot its use in math.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274110